# Visual C# very poor performance in while loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, while-loop

I am having some trouble with `while` loops in C#. This happens let's say once per week.
I am looping through a SQL Server data reader and I read simple strings, doubles etc ... I don't understand why this happens once in a while. If there were a problem in my code then its performance should be ALWAYS poor.

To be more specific, when this happens, when I set a breakpoint, the thread breaks after 3 or 4 seconds. And the weirdest thing is that if I press F5 or if I "step-by-step" the loop, it takes less time !

That's really weird and it makes me crazy.

I am wondering if someone ever encountered this type of weird deal.

Thanks in advance for your replies !

PS : The `while` loop is executed by a particular thread (not the main one).

PS 2 : here is my code

```
reader = DBConnect.GetInstance.ExecuteReader(request.ToString(), out connection, timeOut);

while (reader.Read())
{
    SourceInst sourceInst = new SourceInst();
    sourceInst.Load(reader);
    sourceInstList.Add(sourceInst);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code. It's very hard to help you without knowing what the code looks like. It could easily be a transient network issue, or the database being busy, etc.

Comment: The problem is more likely to be related to your SQL server database than your C# code, but with information you posted, we can only guess.

Comment: How do you know its the `foreach` block that is running slow ? Are you sure your threads are synchronized?

Comment: Sorry guys, I added the code. And it's a `while` loop :-)

Comment: As @recursive says, if you are looping over SQL data over a wire, obviously you are experiencing intermittent poor performance with either the database or your network.

Comment: I don't think it's a network/DB issue because the query is executed before looping. And to add some weirdness, the same piece of code executes with absolutely no problem with another query ...

Comment: What does this have to do with multithreading? I mean, there's nothing in the code to indicate multithreading in any way responsible...

Comment: I thought that maybe multithreading would be the the only possible answer because I didn't find a plausible explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database performance is likely varying, thus causing your issues. The `SqlDataReader` provides a stream to your database and does not buffer in memory. Your assumption that the "query is executed before looping" is incorrect. The stream remains open and you're reading one record at a time from the data source via cursor with this loop. Therefore, as your DB performance fluctuates, so does your loop's performance. It does not load and buffer all records into memory prior to the loop - you can do that if you like but I don't recommend it in terms of memory usage.

Comment: The assumption that the "query is executed before looping" is indeed incorrect and so ambitious :-). Thanks for your reply @DavidH. More info about the `SqlDataReader` [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldatareader).